# Can we show a Big Object with lightning-record-form in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform, big-object

I want to show my custom big object in LWC lightning-record-form ?

Is it possible ?

When i do this i get this error :

[image]

Code for the form :

```
<lightning-record-form
    record-id={selectedBigObject.Id}
    object-api-name="Custom_Big_Object__b"
    layout-type="Full"
    columns="2"
    mode="readonly"
    onsubmit={handleSubmit}>
 </lightning-record-form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lightning-record-form` only supports the objects supported by [UI-API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_supported_objects.htm).

As big objects don't have standard SF UI i belive the UI API doesn't support it and thus cant be used in `lightning-record-form`

Comment: Yes, You are totaly right , In order to show a Big Object you need to write your custom UI.